# Rails 4 scoped model with association also scoped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scope

I have 2 models, Student(has_many schedules) and Schedule and what I want is to find All students that have a active schedule today.

What I have now:

Student model:

```
scope :training_today, -> { joins(:schedules) & Schedule.active & Schedule.from_today }
```

Both schedule scopes work fine. See here:

```
$ Schedule.active.from_today

Schedule Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "schedules".* FROM "schedules"  WHERE "schedules"."active" = 't' AND "schedules"."day" = 4  ORDER BY day ASC
=> [#<Schedule id: 47, student_id: 2, hour: "11", active: true, created_at: "2014-05-18 23:26:34", updated_at: "2014-06-05 19:04:02", day: 4>,
#<Schedule id: 5, student_id: 1, hour: "08:00", active: true, created_at: "2014-05-16 02:54:21", updated_at: "2014-06-05 20:50:07", day: 4>]
```

What I want:

From my Student model I want to find only those from the query above(ids 1 and 2). Using the scope Student.training_today I get nothing(empty array). How can I get the correct students ?

Comment: can you post the query resulted when calling training_today?

Comment: "[]" I said that in the question =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what represents the `day` value in your Database, but this code implies that is it the week-day of this date:

```
scope :training_today, -> {
  includes(:schedules).where(schedules: { active: true, day: Date.current.wday }) 
}
```

Comment: I'm using enum to save the day. So it is an integer and this wday works. Because I'm using Rails 4.1 I had to change the block to that arrow. I will edit the answer. But the idea worked just fine. Thanks